# avg file server edition, how many connections?

Tags: windows-server-2003, anti-virus, file-server

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hello,
We have antivirus for all workstations except our file server. I was checking AVG File Server Edition but I didn't understand what do they mean by asking number of connections which starts from 2 up to 200?

http://www.avg.com/gb-en/avg-file-server-edition

Do they mean numbers of workstations?
Why number of workstations matter, it's just a file server?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To quote from the page you linked to - the sentence DIRECTLY above the connection slection:

> Licensing and pricing is by the number
>   of server connections

Not very clear. Now, who could answer that?

Hm. Let me see the page.

Right, top, yellow:

> Help with purchase Our team of
>   experienced AVG Sales Representatives
>   is standing by to help!

I suggest you contact them. There is a phone number, email and a contact form.

Comment: While the tone of the response isn't necessarily the nicest in my opinion, when you're talking about specifics involving licensing of a particular product, TomTom is right...you need to talk to the company. Each company can potentially have their own slant on the language of their licensing and terms. One of the primary reasons I prefer headaches of free software to headaches of proprietary stuff...

Comment: In the past it was nice when AVG responded via email or phone to such questions!  This is why I searched the question.  I of course tried the route of "Experienced Sales Reps" first :)